# Android Studio build for older architecture (ARMV6)

Tags: android

I am working on an app that needs compatibility with Android API 10.
I got a device running this API and when i try to run the app, it gives me Missing Native Library.

After searching online I found out that the external library .SO files are located only in armeabi-v7a, and i assume because the older device uses ARMv6, this is why the library can not be loaded in the older phone.

The question is, which jniLibs folder is used to search for the library, to be loaded in ARMv6 architecture? And another question is how to generate the library in this folder or what to do?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, just had to create folder armeabi and copy the .so files there.